# Value assign from the next line with str_match in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to assign Sunil Raperia to the variable. The value is in the next line though. I am giving an example below:

```
y = c("Name:

   Sunil Raperia")
```

`stringr::str_match(y, "Name: (.*) ")[, 2]` is not able to capture the value when the value is in the next line. `stringr::str_match(y, "Name: (.*) " /n)[, 2]` is not solving it though .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for whitespace :

```
stringr::str_match(y, "Name:\\s+(.*)")[, 2]
#[1] "Sunil Raperia"
```

and same with `sub` in base R :

```
sub("Name:\\s+(.*)", "\\1", y)
```

Comment: **yy = c("I am having a Full Name Sunil Raperia 4,50,000.00")**

Using the below function gives me **Sunil Raperia**,

**stringr::str_match(yy, "Name (.*) ")[,2]**

As per the requirement it should be Sunil Raperia 4,50,000.00

Is there anything which I am missing in the function?

Comment: @SunilRaperia Remove the space at the end. `stringr::str_match(yy, "Name (.*)")[,2]`. Usually, with regex there is no general solution and mostly it depends on the text/string that you have.

Comment: Country: Singapore or India, where you are currently located. In my code, "Singapore or India, where you are currently located" is in the next line. I am trying to assign with the above code, but its not working. Need to assign, 
"Singapore or India" to Country from the next line.

Comment: @SunilRaperia Maybe remove `"\n"` from the lines first? `gsub("\n", "", y)`

Comment: My full name Sunil Kumar Raperia living in Singapore. From the line I am trying to assign Sunil Kumar Raperia to Name. I am using the following code: stringr::str_match(text," full name (?:\\s*:)?\\s*([\\w'-]+(?:\\s+[\\w'-]+){2})")[,2]. But its not capuring the next 3 words.

Comment: works fine for me. `str_match('My full name Sunil Kumar Raperia living in Singapore.', "full name (?:\\s*:)?\\s*([\\w'-]+(?:\\s+[\\w'-]+){2})")[, 2]`

Comment: names <- str_match('My full name Sunil Kumar, Raperia living in Singapore.', "full name (?:\\s*:)?\\s*([\\w'-]+(?:\\s+[\\w'-]+){2})")[, 2]. Actually there is , after Kumar. I forget to mention. Just an update. The name is Sunil Kumar, Raperia

Comment: `str_match('My full name Sunil Kumar, Raperia living in Singapore.', "full name (\\w+\\s+\\w+,?\\s+\\w+)")[, 2]`